# Scala WS exception error (Web page returned instead of Json)

Tags: json, web-services, scala, rest, playframework

I am using Play scala WS to send a REST api call to a web server and sometimes get an exception error. Json is sent to the server and the response from the server could be one of the following.

1. Server returns a valid Json response.
2. Server returns "No valid Json found"
3. Server returns an error web page that triggers the exception error com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

How do I modify the code below to get the contents of the web page without the exception error?

```
import play.api.libs.ws._

var tempText = Helpers.await(WS.url("localhost:9000/someApi").post(jsonToSend)).body
println(tempText)
tempJson = Json.parse(tempText)
println(tempJson)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much depends on how "correct" that downstream API server is.

In a perfect world, we could probably assert the following facts:

1. Success case => HTTP `status` is `200`, HTTP `Content-Type` header is `application/json`
2. "No valid Json found" => HTTP `status` is `404` or similar non-200, HTTP `Content-Type` header is `application/json`
3. "Error web page" => HTTP `status` is not `200`, `Content-Type` is `text/html`

**If** the above assertions are all true, then we can simply put a little bit of "protection" around our response-handling rather than just jumping in and trying to parse it as JSON:

```
val futureOptionalResult = WS.url("localhost").post("...").map { response =>
  response.status match {
    case 200 => {
      println(response.body)
      println(response.json)
      Some(response.json)
    }
    case _ => {
      println(s"Not OK: ${response.status} - body is: ${response.body}")
      None
    }
  }
}
```

Some notes:

- Doing it asynchronously is just as easy as using an `await` and scales better
- `response.json` returns the same thing as your explicit `Json.parse` on the body
- I'm returning an `Option[JsValue]` that holds the returned JSON if it worked

If the above assumptions are *not* true, deeper inspection of the `Content-Type` header, finer-grained switching on the `status` value and/or other attributes of the `response` will probably be needed. Good luck!